# How do I Open all html files in a folder in multiple browser types with a new tab for each file

Tags: html, internet-explorer, batch-file

I'm trying to test a html file in all browsers. Is there a way using the command line to open all of the .html files in a directory in Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, etc with each file in its own tab in each browser to ensure that the html files are working properly across all internet browsers?

This code I have below opens all of the html files but each in a new window for each browser. I'm trying to consolidate all of the files to stick to one browser window.

```
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL
PUSHD "C:\pathtohtmlfiles"
FOR %%a IN (*.htm *.html) DO (
    REM START "Internet Explorer" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" "file://%CD%\%%a"
    START "Firefox" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -new-tab "file://%CD%\%%a"
    START "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "file://%CD%\%%a"
)
POPD
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could only start multiple html files in the same window if I called them in the same command, perhaps this will work for you -

```
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL
SET files=
PUSHD "C:\pathtohtmlfiles"
FOR %%a IN (*.htm *.html) DO SET files=%files% "%%a"
START "Firefox" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" %files%
START "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" %files%
POPD
```

The `file://` was unnecessary for me.

Comment: I didn't test it, It's probably to do with my setting of the `files` variable. I will fiddle with it later. However, I know that at least Chrome can open multiple files in the same window like so: `start Chrome test.html test1.html`.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the below script is working fine for my Chrome and FF, however, I tried a few ways but still can't figure out the IE - it always to open in a new windows

```
@ECHO OFF 
for /r "C:\pathtohtmlfiles" %%A in (*.htm*) do (
    START "Internet Explorer" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" "file://%%A"
    START "Firefox" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "file://%%A"
    START "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "file://%%A"
)
```

Comment: ps, please correct the Firefox path as my FF is under x86 folder